# Agregando elementos a una Lista

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8

```
Map<Integer,Paciente> listaPacientes;
```

tengo este metodo que dada una lista de pacientes  me devuelve otra lista con los dni de los pacientes que no se vacunaron
pero el problema es que no los estaria agregando a la lista, sabrian el por que ?
en la clase persona tengo como atributos Integer dni y boolean seVacuno entre otros

```
public List<Integer> listaDeEspera(){
        List<Integer> pacientesConTurnos = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(Paciente paciente : listaPacientes.values()) {
            if(paciente.seVacuno==false)
                pacientesConTurnos.add(paciente.dni);
        }
        return pacientesConTurnos;
    }
```

Comment: La condición es que todos los pacientes no se hayan vacunado para agregarlos. ¿Estás segura qué hay pacientes con dicha propiedad con un valor de falso? ¿Podrías poner el código de tu clase paciente?

Comment: También, cómo estás accediendo en ese método a la variable listaPacientes? No veo que la estes mandando en el método, así que asumo que esa lista está dentro de otra clase en la que listaPacientes es una propiedad.

Comment: Solo una apreciación. desconozco el país en el que vives y el formato del dni, pero como aquí en España usamos una letra añadida al número, y ese número es susceptible de repetirse, yo te aconsejaría guardar ese dato como string y así, si en tu formato hay letra, almacenarla junto al número correspondiente y evitar que pueda repetirse.